# In an AOSP Android.mk file, how do I execute a command and fail the build if the command fails?

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

In an Android.mk file, I have the following line which executes a bash script:

```
$(info $(shell ($(LOCAL_PATH)/build.sh)))
```

However, if the command fails the build continues rather than quitting.

How do I make the whole build fail in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dump `stdout`, test the exit status, and error out on failure:

```
ifneq (0,$(shell >/dev/null command doesnotexist ; echo $$?))
  $(error "not good")
endif
```

Here's what failure looks like:

```
[user@host]$ make 
/bin/sh: doesnotexist: command not found
Makefile:6: *** not good.  Stop.
[user@host]$
```

If you want to see `stdout`, then you can save it to a variable and test only the `lastword`:

```
FOOBAR_OUTPUT := $(shell echo "I hope this works" ; command foobar ; echo $$?)
$(info $$(FOOBAR_OUTPUT) == $(FOOBAR_OUTPUT))
$(info $$(lastword $$(FOOBAR_OUTPUT)) == $(lastword $(FOOBAR_OUTPUT)))
ifneq (0,$(lastword $(FOOBAR_OUTPUT)))
  $(error not good)
endif
```

which gives

```
$ make
/bin/sh: foobar: command not found
$(FOOBAR_OUTPUT) == I hope this works 127
$(lastword $(FOOBAR_OUTPUT)) == 127
Makefile:12: *** not good.  Stop.
```

Comment: Thanks, this works quite well but how do I make it also show stdout in the console as well as stderr?

Comment: @CameronMartin, excellent point. I've amended my answer with a trick to capture `stdout` and test via `lastword`.